# How could you define more grid areas than the ones created by the rows and columns you created?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm taking a course on udacity about web development, and I'm super confused about the concept of named grid areas.
They give the example below as an illustration, but I just don't get it.

```
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 600px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
  "sd sd sd main main main main main"
  "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft"; }
```

My question is the following: Why define grid rows, and grid columns when you're not going to stick to them when you name your areas? For example, when I define 2 rows and 2 columns, shouldn't I name 4 areas? How can I name more? How could the browser even understand this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post code as image. Better post it as text in your question so that nobody has to retype it. I would also suggest you to use the general [css] tag. Remember, the TAGS attract the right audience to your question, so if you use only very specific tags you get less audience and the audience you want don't see that question.

Comment: @fcdt Thanks! I'll edit my question.

Comment: I feel like there's code missing for this to *really* make sense. Do you have any supporting HTML with that, or are you only presented with CSS?

Comment: You are defining the columns and rows to have a unique width and height other than the default fractional unit used to define them.

Comment: @m4n0 I thought so too at first, but I don't think this is correct (I assume I'm wrong of course)
If I'm defining the unique width and height for the rows and columns of my grid, shouldn't I define it once? Or maybe I should define it for every row/column I'll use? But from the examples I was presented, that does not seem to be the case. I've seen examples in which people define 2-3 rows, and go on to name areas involving 6-7 rows like the example I posted. They defined 2 rows, but named 3. What is the size of the 3rd row then?

Comment: If you marked that answer, then does my comment make sense now?

Comment: @m4n0 Yes! But you didn't really explain a lot tho. Thanks anyway! I appreciate the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 250px 600px;
  grid-template-areas: "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd" "sd sd sd main main main main main" "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft";
}

.item {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>

  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

This will result in
[image]

https://codepen.io/abl20/pen/VwadEwM

Here you are able to see that the grid areas point out when the next element will start on a new line. The grid-templates cols and rows just make sure how wide and tall the first items are in their row and col are.

Comment: Oh! Now it makes sense! Thanks a lot!